# Search function with multiple WHERE clauses from the same columns

Tags: php, sql, prestashop-1.6

I have a slight issue with a search function I am developing and I would need your help.

To summarize, there is a list of products displayed to the users; upon clicking on different criteria, the user can reduce the size of this list and find the right product.

Example of search criteria:

[image]

For instance, it will get all the products from category 222. Then if the user clicks on the color "D", it will show only the products with color "D". If the users adds the color "E", it will show products with either one.

The very important thing is, if the user clicks on color "D", color "E" and then on clarity "FL" and clarity "IF"; it has to show the products with `((color = D OR color = E) AND (clarity = FL OR clarity = IF))`.

However, the database is not structured that way and all the different options (color D, color E, color E, clarity FL, clarity IF...) are under the same column entitled id_feature_value:

[image]

So far, here is my sql request (simplified for readability):

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` c ON (c.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'feature_product` f ON (f.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)
                WHERE c.`id_category` = 222 '.$searchValues.
                ' GROUP BY f.`id_product` ORDER BY p.`id_product` DESC LIMIT '.$scroll.',20';
```

The `$searchValues` variable corresponds to what is explained above and - unfortunately and obviously - does not work.

The `$scroll` variable corresponds to the level of scroll of the users. This function gathers the 20 first items and, when the user reaches the bottom, will bring the 20 next entries.

I have had a look at the `IN` possibility however I couldn't not make it work because of the `AND` and `OR` combination.

Can you assist me a bit with this?

Let me know if you need additional information.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Make sure you're preventing SQL injection by binding parameters and using prepared statments!

Comment: Welcome to EAV design.  You rarely need this level of flexibility in a design (especially because it's a royal _pain_ to query in the first place).  A more usual design (ie, columns for `carat`, `color`, etc) tends to be easier to write these kinds of queries for - would you be up to changing your schema (lots of work, though)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your conditions inside of `HAVING COUNT`. For example, suppose `id_feature = 20` represents the color and values `1142,1143` represent different colors. Then the query below would count how many of these two colors each product has and only return those that have 1 or more. You can add as many `AND COUNT(CASE ...` conditions as needed.

```
GROUP BY f.`id_product`
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN id_feature = 20 
            AND id_feature_value IN (1142,1143)
        THEN 1
        END) > 0

    AND COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN id_feature = 23 
            AND id_feature_value IN (233,234)
        THEN 1
        END) > 0
```

**Edit**

Another approach, which may be faster, is to use `EXISTS` i.e.

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM feature_product
    WHERE id_feature = 20
    AND id_feature_value IN (1142,1143)
    AND id_product = p.id
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM feature_product
    WHERE id_feature = 23
    AND id_feature_value IN (233,234)
    AND id_product = p.id
)
```

Comment: It sounds good! Let me try this and upvote you if it's correct. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The second solution works perfectly! Just a reminder for other people with the same issue; remember to remove the left join about the table for which you are looking into several rows from your query!